# In a Hash where every value is an array, how to find a key using an array item?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a Hash. In it, the value of every key is an array. I want to test if a value is in one of the arrays, and if so, to which key it corresponds. For example, let's say I'm writing a command line program with a list of command, and every command has a few nicknames, like so:

```
commands = {
  :exit => ['exit', 'ex'],
  :start_car => ['start_engine', 'start'],
  :accelerate => ['speed_up', 'accelerate'],
  :help => ['help', '?']
}
```

So if I wanted to start the car, I could enter either `start_engine` or `start` and both would work.

Let's also say I need a function to test whether or not a given string is name for a command. If not, return `false`. If so, return the name of the command, like so:

```
def is_command? string
  if # string is a nickname
    # return the key to which it belongs, i.e. 'ex' to :exit
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

I tried going through the function lists for Hashes and Arrays, but I couldn't find anything, and I can't even start to think about how to Google something like this. Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be best to build an inverted hash, like this

```
commands = {
  :exit       => ['exit', 'ex'],
  :start_car  => ['start_engine', 'start'],
  :accelerate => ['speed_up', 'accelerate'],
  :help       => ['help', '?'],
}

command_for = {}
commands.each_pair do
  | cmd, names |
  names.each { |name| command_for[name] = cmd }
end

puts command_for['start']
puts command_for['help']
puts command_for['?']
```

**output**

```
start_car
help
help
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how this works, or what this does that the top solution doesn't.

Comment: @EdenLandau, Efficient lookups. The program above creates a hash where the keys are every nickname, and the value for each key is the commmand.  When you lookup "?", BAM!, you get the command.  On the other hand, the first solution plods through every array of every key looking for a match.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much, I implemented this solution instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use `find`:

```
commands = {:exit => ['exit', 'ex'], :start_car => ['start_engine', 'start'], :accelerate => ['speed_up', 'accelerate'], :help => ['help', '?']}
commands.find { |key,value| value.include?( '?' ) }
> [:help, ["help", "?"]]
```

Comment: Bravo! Very elegant.  Man I love Enumerable and it's associated methods.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Except that, if this sort of thing is happening a lot, the inverse hash should be built to make it a lot faster